# "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid" for Google Maps link

Tags: iphone, google-maps, mobile-safari

I have an iPhone 4s with iOS7 that doesn't have the Google Maps app installed on it. Whenever I try to navigate to a location link on it, it flashes an error at me that says:

```
Cannot Open Page
Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid
```

But then the error goes away (without having to hit OK) and the map shows up, and all subsequent Google Maps links load without this error. When I clear my cache, the error shows up again, but only for the first time, and again disappears on its own.

This is the link in question that I am using, but I have tested it with multiple links and the problem seems to be persistent:

https://www.google.com/maps/place/Kraftwork/@39.971494,-75.127336,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x6db3f86eca2f8b45?hl=en

Any idea what's causing this problem?

To be specific, this problem exists as a result of straight html and just attempting to click a maps link.

Comment: Same issue here, any luck with this? my case is more consistent, not just first time opening the link

Comment: Same Issue, I wish we had a solution

Answer (score 0):

I treid  to paste to link in the Safari directly and do it programmatically in both iOS 7 and iOS 8 with iPhone 4s, both work for me. Maybe you can try it with iOS 8 simulator with your XCode too.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"https://www.google.com/maps/place/Kraftwork/@39.971494,-75.127336,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x6db3f86eca2f8b45?hl=en"]];
```

Comment: This solution will not work for me since I am doing this with simple HTML. I will revise the question to be more specific.