# Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid for Google Maps on iPad

Tags: ios, google-maps, ipad, safari

We have a link that goes to Google Maps for directions using just the normal format for the Google Maps URL: https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Current+Location/38.8992,-77.0482.

This works fine on google chrome and other browsers don't seem to have this issue either, but somehow on the iPad with OS 8.1.3 using the Safari browser, an alert comes up with the message "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid"

Is anyone else experiencing this issue?

The page still does seem to load, but the alert pops up and needs to be dismissed and detracts from the user experience. Since the link follows the Google Maps API standard and seems to work otherwise, what is the reason this is happening and what can be done to stop this from happening?

Also, something strange happened when after the link works a few times, the message no longer comes up when the user is directed to the page. However, after clearing history and data for the Safari browser on iPad, the problem resurfaces again.

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049228/safari-cannot-open-the-page-because-the-address-is-invalid-for-google-maps-lin ?

Comment: Seems to be a similar problem, but there's no solution on there.

Comment: Which version of the Google Maps app are you using?

Comment: The iPad does not have Google Maps installed at all. The intention is for Google Maps to open in the browser, like it would if I clicked it now in Chrome.

Comment: The error message would make sense if mobile Safari uses app deep linking and tries to see if you have the Google Maps app installed.  Downloading the app might get rid of that message, but I think you should file a bug with the Safari team.

Comment: Honestly, I think this has been deliberately broken by Google to force you to use their app.  I have location services turned off for Safari and I don't want to use an app when I already have a browser--the browser has limited control over my iPad as compared to the average app.  You may not have noticed but it's broken from Google -> "maps" -> click link for Google Maps = invalid address.  But if you just enter in https://maps.google.com then it seems to work.  Obviously, their own redirect from the home page--having detected iOS--is the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else arrived here but wasn't getting this error because of a Google Maps link, Look at any JS you have listening to the click event of the link.

In my case, I had discovered a previous developer added a

```
e.preventDefault();
```

to the `click` event.

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth noting that--as a PhoneGap developer--I've verified that the iOS's GPS data appears to be higher quality than that, say, on the Android phone or on an HP laptop.  The number of digits of precision on the iPad is significantly longer than what's available on other platforms.

It could be that when iOS is pushing so many digits of precision that their server is seeing this as an error.  This [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-api/uSi1-8U1GCE) appears to suggest that Google will throw away unnecessary precision but it's possible that a recent update now at Google Maps is choking on the excess.

Also note:  if your phone is set for a language other than English then the Google API expects the word in that language for "current", for example, "votre+location" in French.